# d3.mouse pixel offset in Firefox

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I visualize some data on a timeline. On mousemove I’d like to show a line and the current hovered time. It works as expected in Chrome and Safari but in Firefox (tested in 44 & 45) there is an offset: The returned pixel value is always lacking half the width of the whole SVG.

E.g., when hovering the left side of the visualization, I expect the value of `d3.mouse` to equal `0`, but it is `-300`.

See this test case on Codepen: http://codepen.io/ro-ka/pen/bpqazK?editors=0010  The function in question is at the bottom.

Any ideas what’s wrong with it?

Comment: It's because the `transform: translate()`  CSS function, if you disable this it works perfectly. Maybe there are another CSS property to solve this 2D transform

Comment: Great one! That’s it! Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Yeah, here you are :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the transform: translate() CSS function, if you disable this it works perfectly. Maybe there are another CSS property to solve this 2D transform.

Ideas:

1. You can wrap the `<svg>` element into a DIV that contains these perfect-center styles and remove them from svg object.
2. Center with a fixed meassurement without translate.

Good luck!